# My autoencoder for tfidf vectors is yielding the same output for different text inputs

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, autoencoder

I have been attempting to implement an autoencoder for my task of dimensionality reduction, to input into a nearest neighbor model, and I realized that all the neighbors ended up being zero distance from the other, I realized the issue stemmed from the autoencoder, which yielded a similar output for different texts.

I have already attempted to change the number of layers, regularizer as well as the activation for the output layer ( i used linear since that was supposed to be the best for text data).
my dataframes for desc and req have shapes of (31080, 471494) (31080, 169214) respectively, mostly sparse data, which i got from using tfidf on the initital raw text data.

```
class SparseDataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, X, batch_size):
        self.X = X
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n_samples = X.shape[0]

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(self.n_samples / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        start = idx * self.batch_size
        end = min(start + self.batch_size, self.n_samples)
        batch_X = self.X[start:end].toarray()
        return batch_X, batch_X  # Autoencoder gets the same data as input and target


combined_vecs_sparse = hstack([df_desc.sparse.to_coo(), df_req.sparse.to_coo()])


# Define early stopping callback
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, restore_best_weights=True)

# Split the data
X_train, X_val = train_test_split(combined_vecs_sparse, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
X_train = X_train.tocsr()
X_val = X_val.tocsr()
before_memory = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss
input_dim = X_train.shape[1]  # Number of features

# Define the autoencoder structure
input_layer = Input(shape=(input_dim,))

encoded = Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001))(input_layer)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001))(encoded)
encoded = Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001))(encoded)  # Encoded representation
decoded = Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001))(encoded)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001))(decoded)
decoded = Dense(input_dim, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

autoencoder = Model(input_layer, decoded)

# Compile and train the autoencoder
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

How to resolve this?